# iphone - prevent uiscrollview from scrolling by touch

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I've a scrollview and on both sides, I've two buttons left and right.

when i click the scroll view will move left and when right button is clicked it will move right side. My scrollview has 20 buttons (approx) & on click of each button some action is performed.

Everything is perfectly implemented and working fine.

Only thing i couldn't implement is to prevent scrolling by touch. I don't want user to scroll the scrollview manually. How can i prevent it from scrolling by touch and still able to click the buttons inside the scrollview ?

Comment: This sounds like a major problem you're introducing. You're writing code for a touch oriented device, where people are familiar with scrolling by dragging their fingers, and it's the most natural action. I'm just going to urge you to reconsider your design. Think of your users.

Comment: If you don't want the touch to work, why are you using a scrollview at all? Just use a normal UIView.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Try setting `yourScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;`. That should do exactly what you want.

Comment: I get that is is not allowed so try setting it through the setter method `[scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];`

Comment: `yourScrollView.isScrollEnabled = false` is correct syntax if you use Swift.

Comment: Very nice ratio of upvotes to characters-in-answer! Thx.

Comment: Thanks. Also usable for WKWebView ... webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false;

Answer (score 6):

**Swift**, set `scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false` and it should work!

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3**

```
self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

If those buttons are the only interface for users, disable 'User Interaction Enabled' option of the scroll view in the Interface Builder. Or, programmatically, set `userInteractionEnabled` property to NO.

Comment: Good one! My scrollView scrolls conforming a tableView, so I prefer the solution thah keeps it scrolling, but without user interaction enable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your issue is that when using UIView.animate and the options:
[.allowUserInteraction], is *not* set.
After this option set, the scrollview should stop on tap.